# Refer to a class/method

Tags: c#, .net

I have this method in my `Calories` class which inherits from the `User` class:

```
class Calories : User
{
    public void CalcuateCaloriesMale()
    {
        var user = new User();
        var equation = (10 * user.Weight) + (6.25 * user.Height) - (5 * user.Age) + 5;
        Console.WriteLine("Based on the Mifflin – St Jeor Formula You need to eat {0} Kalories a day\nTo Gain Weight ", equation);

    }
}
```

And I have this code in Program.cs

```
if (newGoal.GoalStatusGainWeight ==  true)
{
    var calories = new Calories();

    switch (newUser.Gender)
    {
        case "m":
             calories.CalcuateCaloriesMale();
             break;
```

Now I don't understand how to make the `Calories` class know what the user has typed in at the beginning.

```
newUser.Name = Question.AskString("Name: ");
newUser.Age = Question.AskInt("Age: ");
newUser.Gender = Question.AskString("Gender(m/f): ");
newUser.Height = Question.AskInt("Height(cm): ");
newUser.Weight = Question.AskInt("Weight(kg): ");
```

The `Calories` class doesn't take into consideration what the user has typed in.

I though I can use make a new User, but I guess my thinking was wrong.

What am I doing wrong? How can I imagine this working so I can learn it better?

Comment: Why did you create a new class? Why not just make a method (either on `User` or that takes a `User` as parameter)? It seems you need to go through a basic tutorial, in your code there is **no** connection between `newUser` and the `user` in `CalcuateCaloriesMale`

Comment: Well how do i do that ?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/methods

Comment: Following line is wrong : var user = new User();.  You are creating a new instance of the User class. You can use this.Name to get the name or just Name.

Answer (score 0):

You should not be Writing in the method.
For sure you should not be creating a new user in the method.

```
public string CalcuateCaloriesMale()
{
    var equation = (10 * user.Weight) + (6.25 * user.Height) - (5 * user.Age) + 5;
    return equation ;
}
```

You should have one CalcuateCalories as you know if the user if m/f.